# what's the correct shorthand syntax when using multiple css background images/gradients?

Tags: css, background, background-image

I need to attach multiple backgrounds to an element via CSS and I can't use `:before/:after`.

I'm wondering what the correct syntax to use multiple CSS background image is.

There is a bunch of suggested ways I found, like [here](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/multiple-bg-css-gradients) or [here](http://css-tricks.com/stacking-order-of-multiple-backgrounds/), but I can get neither of these:

```
background: url(…) 0 0 repeat, url(…) 5px 5px no-repeat #FFF;
background: url(…) 600px 10px no-repeat, url(…) 10px 10px no-repeat;
```

to work.

This is what I currently have:

```
background-image: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) url("img/icons-18-white.png") no-repeat 0% 50%,linear-gradient( #9ad945, #7eb238 );
```

which is ignored. Only when I supply the pure url, it works:

```
background-image: url("img/icons-18-white.png") , linear-gradient( #9ad945, #7eb238 );
```

**Question:**
I'm specifically looking for a way to set `background-size/position/repeat` per image, so if someone could point me to the correct syntax, would be really nice!

**EDIT**:
Adding `scroll` and replacing `background-image` with `background`

```
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) url("http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/images/icons-18-white.png") no-repeat scroll 0% 50%, linear-gradient( #9ad945, #7eb238 );
```

does not work.

Comment: i don't think this is possible. and why would you do this?

Comment: http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/

Comment: it should be possible ,but i can't get it to work. See my latest edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two main issues with what you have that prevent it from working:

- The shorthand property is `background`, not `background-image`.
- The background color, which in your case is `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)`, must be specified last.

If the shorthand syntax ends up too confusing, you can always set the individual properties separately, passing them the same number of comma-separated values corresponding to the number of background layers (CSS gradients are considered to be images). However if you set `background-color` you may only specify it once.

Remember that when specifying multiple backgrounds, the order in which they are drawn is first to last, top to bottom. This is why the color is expected to come last in a shorthand declaration. [This section of the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#layering) describes it, while [this section](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background) contains the full syntax:

> Value: `[ <bg-layer> , ]* <final-bg-layer>`
>
> Where
>
> ```
> <bg-layer> = <bg-image> || <position> [ / <bg-size> ]? || <repeat-style> || <attachment> || <box>{1,2} 
>
> <final-bg-layer> = <bg-image> || <position> [ / <bg-size> ]? || <repeat-style> || <attachment> || <box>{1,2} || <'background-color'>
> ```

Details about layering in individual properties can be found in their respective sections.

If you're trying to superimpose the background graphic over an `rgba()` color, you may not be able to add a gradient beneath that layer without applying the gradient to a `:before` box instead. Alternatively, if you mix the 40% black color into the gradient stops themselves, you can remove the `rgba()` color altogether leaving just the graphic and the gradient.

Comment: He needs short hand for multiple backgrounds..so instead of `background: 1, 2; background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;` he needs `background: 1, 2, no-repeat, repeat;`

Comment: +1 Nice answer  .. Also take a look at [3.1. Layering Multiple Background Images](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#layering) for more info

Comment: @Mr.Alien: so I can't set no-repeat, repeat "per background"

Comment: @Adrift: now I really learned something! Thanks for the link!

Comment: @Adrift: Editing my answer to include the relevant links.

Comment: @frequent You need to set it differently, `background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat` means `no-repeat` for background 1 and `repeat` for background 2, separate it by commas, but NO you cannot have a long string of multiple short hand declarations

Comment: @Mr.Alien: just found that out, too. But it works with separate declarations.

Comment: @BoltClock: do you want to add an example of how to set it up with separate declarations and that `background-image: 1,2 need background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat`. That would help anyone else stumbling across this.

Comment: @frequent Ya it will and that's the way to declare multiple backgrounds :)